# Displaying div on hover in a different place

Tags: html, css, hover, display, displaytag

I know how to display one div when you hover over another using the CSS:

```css
.showme {
  display: none;
}

.showhim:hover .showme {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="showhim">HOVER ME
  <div class="showme">hai</div>
</div>
```

But the new div is displayed underneath the hover div.
How can i have a div that when you hover it, displays another div that may be somewhere else on the page e.g above the hover one.
Rather than it displaying under the hover div.

Comment: are you talking about same child div `showme`?

Comment: yes, i want the `showme` div somewhere else on the page rather than underneath the `showhim` div

Comment: where do you want to be placed then? and is it have to be child div only?

Comment: i would like to be placed above the `showhim` div. I dont know what the second question is asking

Comment: I was asking if the div has to be inside the other div or it should be outside. never mind I have shared the answer let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML still looks like

```
<div class="showhim">HOVER ME
    <div class="showme">hai</div>
</div>
```

In that case, you can just assign an absolute or fixed position to the `div` with class `showme` and still use the same CSS.

If the `showme` div cannot be a child of the `showhim` div, then you can try placing it as a sibling.

```
<div class="showhim">HOVER ME</div>
<div class="showme">hai</div>
```

Once that is done, you can modify your CSS in the following manner

```
.showme {
    display: none;
}

.showhim:hover ~ .showme {
    display: block;
}
```

The ~ can be used to select sibling elements that appear **after** the current element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```css
.showhim{
    margin-top:50px;
}

.showme {
  display: none;
}

.showhim:hover .showme {
display:block;
border:1px solid red;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="showhim">HOVER ME 
    <div class="showme">hai</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for this, unfortunately it didn't work to answer the other question, yes the div needs to be inside the other div. i'm unsure why but i doesn't work without the one div being inside the other

Comment: My answer shows the same, mean `div` is within the parent `div`. and on hover it is displaying at the top. what else am I missing here?

Comment: oh i didnt see that, i should have worked in the case. Because it didnt work i assumed it was because the div where separate, i never looked. it should have worked, i dunno why it didnt.

Comment: how about this? https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/gs7r0mq1/29/ and what browser are you using to verify?

Comment: Its working on the link, but not when i copy it into my code. i'm using chrome browser

Comment: Then it is not the code, there might be other code is making it stopping its visibility. you need to check that.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help. ill have a look at my code to see whats up.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to shift the child div above its parent when the parent is hovered. If you know about positioning then you can use it. If you don't know then follow this code snippet.

```css
      div{
        height: 30px;
      }
      .parent:hover .child{
        position: relative;
        bottom: 30px;
      }
      .parent:hover + .brother{
        position: relative;
        left: 30px;
      }
```

```html
  <div class="parent">
        hoverme
        <div class="child">hi</div>
  </div>
  <div class="brother">brother</div>
```

Here I assigned the `child` a relative position which allows you to move it relative to its current position and `bottom` property pushes it above `30px`. Here if you don't want any overlapping then you will have to keep account for the `height` of parent or in this case `parent` div. `relative` position will be better then `absolute`. Also sibling movement is possible and is shown in the css.

Answer (score 0):

If Javascript is an option, you can easily toggle the `display` property like this:

```js
var showmeElement = document.getElementsByClassName('showme')[0];

function toggleSibling(shouldShow) {
  if(shouldShow) {
    showmeElement.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    showmeElement.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.showme {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="showme" onmouseover="toggleSibling(true)" onmouseout="toggleSibling(false)">B</div>
<div class="showhim" onmouseover="toggleSibling(true)" onmouseout="toggleSibling(false)">A</div>
```

Otherwise, with CSS, the only way to target `showme` using `showhim` is by `sibling` / children selectors, with `showhim` being higher in hierarchy (children) or simply higher in DOM (as siblings).

Keep in mind that CSS **can not go upwards in DOM** in order to style elements conditionally, but only downwards.